# How to convert from a power of base two to a power of base 10?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I might have an extremely silly question:
If I have a number, say $2^{32}$ and I need to convert to base 10, how should I do it? I know it should be $4 * 10^9$, but I do not know how did we get it.

I understand that $10$ is $2^3 + 2$, but I cannot understand how to proceed further in my reasoning...

Thanks!

Comment: "I know it should be $4*10^9$" No don't and it's not.  $2^{32}$ has only $2$ as prime factor and $4\cdot 10^9$ has $2$ and $5$.  $4\cdot 10^9 = 2^{11}\cdot 5^9\ne 2^{32}$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Short answer

$2^{10} \approx 10^3$

### Explanation

$$ \log_{10} (2^{32}) = \frac{32 \log 2}{\log 10} \approx 9.633
$$
and since $10^{0.633} \approx 4$,
$$ 2^{32} \approx 4 \cdot 10^9$$.
Or, notice that $2^{10} \approx 10^3$. It follows that $2^{30} \approx 10^9$, and $2^{32} \approx 4 \cdot 10^9$.

Comment: hmm... looks complicated. Any easier way to calculate it? During the class professor asked it straight away and one student immediately answered. Seems like there is some "obvious" way of doing this

Comment: @MaharajaX You can also do it using the fact $2^{10} \approx 10^3$.

Comment: You can also use, $2^{n} = 10^{n*\frac{3}{10}}$

Answer (score 2):

To brush up on algebra rules for exponents, the relevant rule here is that $x^{A*B}=(x^A)^B$. And as the others have already mentioned, $2^{10}=1024≈10^3=1000$. If we pick an example number that is so horrendously gigantic where this small inaccuracy doesn't matter, something like $2^{(2^{20})}=2^{1,048,576}$, you can factor out the exponent and replace it as follows:
$$2^{1,048,576}=2^{10*104,857}=(2^{10})^{104,857}=(10^3)^{104,857}=10^{3*104,857}=10^{314,571}$$
Extremely simple, as long as you remember the algebra fundamentals :)

Answer (score 2):

To work with exponents of different bases, you also need its opposite operation, the logarithm:

$$
2^x = 10^y
$$
applying a $log_{10}$ to the previous equation:

$$
y = \log_{10} 2^x = x·\log_{10}2 = 0.30103x
$$

Therefore (in your question; $2^{32}$):

$$
y = 32×0.30103 = 9.63296
$$
$$
2^{32} \sim 10^{9.6}
$$

Summary:
The factor $0.3$ can be used to multiply the exponent of $2$ to obtain the exponent of $10$, or can be used to divide the exponent of $10$ to get the exponent of $2$, and the approximation is very high, particularly for big exponents.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by noting that $2^{32}\ne 4*10^{9}$. However, $4*10^{9}$ does approximate $2^{32}$ to one significant figure ($2^{32}=4294967296$). So, strictly speaking, you do not seem to know what the answer should be---only a low-order approximation.

There is probably a sophisticated way of solving this problem algebraically... But we also have the option to simply brute-force it.

By "brute forcing," I mean to just write out $2^{32}$ in its integer form by plugging it in to a calculator. This will give you its base 10 representation by default. You will find that you get:

$$2^{32}=4294967296$$

This number is actually short-hand notation for an expansion in powers of 10. In general, any integer can be written:

$$N = \Sigma_{i=0}^{M}A_{i}10^{i},\quad where\quad M \lt \infty$$

It is easiest to see this by starting from the right-side of 4294967296, which represents the single digit term ($6x10^{0}$). The number preceding the single-digit term, to the left, represents a multiple of 10 ($9x10^{1}$), while the third number from the right represents a multiple of 100 ($2x10^{2}$), and so on:

$$2^{32} = 4294967296 \\ =  6(10^{0})+9(10^{1})+2(10^{2})+7(10^{3})\\+6(10^{4})+9(10^{5})+4(10^{6})+9(10^{7})\\+2(10^{8})+4(10^{9})$$

From this expansion, you can see that $4*10^{9}$ is only the lowest order approximation. There are higher-order corrections all the way down to the single-digit scale!

Of course, writing this expansion out explicitly is not necessary. The exact base-10 representation you are looking for is simply found by simultaneously multiplying and dividing the integer-representation we found by its leading power of 10 (which is equivalent to multiplying by 1):

$$2^{32}*\frac{10^{9}}{10^{9}}=\frac{4294967296}{10^{9}}*10^{9}=4.294967296*10^{9}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{32} = (2^{10})^3\cdot 2^2=$

$1024^3\times 4 = $

> I guess this is why you said $2^{32} = 4\times 10^9$.  Of course there is rounding and it isn't equal to that. The trick is to know that $2^{10}=1024 \approx 10^3$ so $2^{32} = 2^{30 + 2}=1024^3\times 4 \approx 10^9 \times 4$. But that's an under approximation.

$(10^3 + 24)^3 \times 4 =$

$(10^9 + 3\cdot 24 \cdot 10^6 + 3\cdot 24^2\cdot 10^3 + 24^3)\times 4$.

Okay.....

$24^2 = (25-1)^2 = 5^4 - 50 + 1 = 625-50-1 = 576$.

And $24^3 = (25-1)^3 = 5^6 - 3\cdot 5^4 + 3\cdot 25 -1 = 25*625 - 1875 + 75 -1= 5*3125 -1801 = 15625-1801 = 13824$

So $2^{32} = 4\times 10^9 + 12\cdot 24\cdot 10^6 + 12\cdot 576\cdot 10^3 + 4\cdot 13824 =$

And $12\cdot 24 = 2\cdot 12^2 = 288$

$12\cdot 576 = 5760 + 1152=6912$

$4\cdot 13824 = 5\times 13824 - 13824 = \frac {138240}2-13824 = 69120-13824 = 55296$

So $2^{32} =$

$4,000,000,000 + 288,000,000 + 6,912,000 + 55,296 =$

$4,288,000,000 + 6,967,296=$

$4,294,967,296$

..... or......

we could figure $2^{10} = 10^3 + \frac 14 10^2 - 1$ so

$2^{30 + 2} = (10^3 + \frac 14 10^2 - 1)^3 \times (5-1)$

Which could get interesting.

$= (10^3 + \frac 1{2^6}10^6 - 1 + 3(10^3\cdot \frac 1{2^4}10^4 + 10^3(-1)^2 +\frac 14\times 10^2\times 10^6 + \frac 1410^2 - 10^6 -\frac 1{2^4}10^4 + 2\cdot 10^3\cdot \frac 14\cdot 10^2 \cdot(-1))(5-1)=$

$= (10^3 + \frac 1{2^6}10^6 - 1 + (5-2)(10^3\cdot \frac 1{2^4}10^4 + 10^3(-1)^2 +\frac 14\times 10^2\times 10^6 + \frac 1410^2 - 10^6 -\frac 1{2^4}10^4 + 2\cdot 10^3\cdot \frac 14\cdot 10^2 \cdot(-1))(5-1)=$

etc.....

Which I *really* don't recommend unless you are morbidly curious and have lots of paper.  But its a goo exercise to deal with only the components $5$ and $2$ and seeing how all digits are a matter of cascade.